# Need to run multiple copies of ASP.net website with datagridview sharing single url C#

Tags: asp.net, t-sql

Have drop-down menu which fills 4 datagridviews based on the branch selected or when the start button is pressed loops through 80 branches.

4 sql server procs, 1 per datagridview, unique sql table, read access, only.

Need to access multiple copies, single url.

Database retrieval time = # of copies run (single asp.net websites over single url called multiple times) * database runtime.

So if it takes 30 seconds for data retrieval, running 3 copies takes 90 seconds and seems to fragment the data or timeout..

I'm using nolocks so there isn't deadlock.

But I need to optimize this.

Should I create one web service and will this solve the problem of hitting the database only one time instead of 1x per single url hit.

Thank you.
David

Comment: So you've got stuff that does things, but you want it faster. Vague enough. Have you started with optimizing the queries in the SPs? Do the results need to be up-to-the-nanosecond or would a cached result up to _n_ minutes old suffice? Buy more memory? Use SSDs?

Comment: "The problem of hitting the database only one time" -- is THAT your goal? To hit the database just once, despite 4 queries? Are they all retrieving exactly the same data?

Comment: Hi Ann. It's a filter against a table (4 tables) based off a drop-down. The drop down selects a branch. The branch filters the table and computes new data which is not a filter.   The total runtime for four datagridviews is 15 seconds.  Yes, optimized, mainly with indexes.  So multiple hits of the website seems to increase the amount of time it takes to retrieve the records. So much so that the datagridviews are only getting partially filled.  If I build a webservice, would I be sharing the database hits better?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this will come down to not really the numbers of records pulled, but that if you are executing multiple SQL statements over and over.

I mean, to fill 4 gv's with 4 queries? That's going to be quite much instant assuming the record set size for each grid is say in the 100 row range. Such a button click and filling the grids should be very low time.

And even if you using a row databound event - once again, it will run fast. But ONLY if you not executing a whole bunch of additional SQL queries. So the number of "hits" or so called SQL statements sent to the database is what for the most part determine the speed of this setup.

So say you have one grid - pulls 100 rows. But then the next grid say needs data based on 100 rows of "new" SQL queries. In that case, what you can often do is fill a reocrdset with the child data - and filter against that recordset, and thus say not have to execute 100 SQL queries, but only 1 query.

So, this will really come down to how many separate SQL queries you execute in total.

To fill 4 grids with 4 queries? I don't see that as being a problem, and thus we are no doubt missing some big "whopper" of a detail you not shared with us.

Expand in your question how many SQL statements are generated in total - that's the bottle neck here. Reduce that, and your performance should be just fine.

And if the 4 simple stored procedures have "cursors" that loop and again generate many SQL commands - get rid of that.

4 basic SQL queries pulls is nothing - something else is at work that you not sharing. Why would each single stored procedure take so very long? That's the detail we are missing here.

Comment: Thank you. The issue here is running multiple copies of the same website off the same url.  So four tables are being hit by multiple runs of the application (nolocks to prevent deadlock).  The question is that the time to hit the tables increases the more copies that are run. Run 3 copies, the cost is 3X as much per application, per datagridview.  If I go with a restful solution, using an api can I get better database efficiency?

Comment: Possibly what I failed to tell you is its not just a filter against 4 unique tables but I'm pulling the data from tables that are being used by the entire company (with nolocks).  Those tables contain millions of records. But those queries run relatively fast. The issue is running multiple web instances off of one url. If I use an API instead of procs to fill the four datagrids, would this help?  I also didn't tell you that when you hit the start button it runs through 80 branches, filling the datagridviews the same way as selecting for one branch.

Comment: don't see how a api will help. Each data pull is the cost - some ajax call + api not really going to do anything. The database does not care if you use some ajax call, some rest page, or anything else. The number of data pulls and how much you pull will determine this issue. and multiple instances of that web site? Hum, well even with one web site, each user has their own data, own state, and one site pulling data, with 4 users vs 4 sites each with 1 user amounts to much the same thing.  That "80" branches has to be reduced. Total number of separate db hits has to be reduced.

Comment: Thank you, the timer was taking over and performing differently on the server than on my local.  Also the UI, timer, and Database were out of synch.  So adding a thread.sleep helped. Adding a longer interval on the timer, helped.  Also putting all the database calls together, instead of 1 connection per database call helped.   Now it runs all the same time. 

The main takeaway I think is that the timer and the Thread.Sleep was the main thing. 

I also had a UI button -  which I added some code so that once it's pushed, if you keep pushing it, it doesn't do anything.  API doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, the timer was taking over and performing differently on the server than on my local.  Also the UI, timer, and Database were out of synch.  So adding a thread.sleep helped. Adding a longer interval on the timer, helped.  Also putting all the database calls together, instead of 1 connection per database call helped.   Now it runs all the same time.

The main takeaway I think is that the timer and the Thread.Sleep was the main thing.

I also had a UI button -  which I added some code so that once it's pushed, if you keep pushing it, it doesn't do anything.

Thank you to everyone that posted answer..

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.